# display recent post in sidebar with post thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I am trying to display recent post with thumbnail,title and author name on by website's blog details page's sidebar . title and author is proper but somehow thumbnail image is not showing proper and also when I check in view source, it's not taking thumbnail size 150*150, it's taking image's original size.

check url:- https://stageserver.co/officework/dev/6-lead-generation-techniques-to-immediately-turn-your-business-into-a-sales-magnet-9-3/

This is the code that I tried:-

```
<!-- Latest News -->
                    <?php $orig_post = $post;
   global $post;
   $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
  if ($tags) {
  $tag_ids = array();
  foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
  $args=array(
  'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'posts_per_page'=>5, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
  'caller_get_posts'=>1
  );
  $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

   echo '<div class="sidebar-widget latest-news"><div class="sidebar-title">
                            <h2>Recent Post</h2>
                        </div>';

  while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  $my_query->the_post(); ?>

 <div class="widget-content">
 <article class="post">
 <div class="post-thumb">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><img src="<?php 
     the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" ></img></a>
</div>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<div class="post-info"><?php the_author(); ?></div>
 </article>
 </div>
 <? }
echo '</div>';
 }
 }
 $post = $orig_post;
 wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

thanks in advance pls help as soon as possible I am new in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the size and other attribute to the the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); function, Default value: 'post-thumbnail'.

Try:

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');


the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium'); // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium_large'); // Medium Large resolution (default 768px x 0px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large'); // Large resolution (default 1024px x 1024px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full'); // Original image resolution (unmodified)

the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) ); // Other resolutions
```

Ok so also the_post_thumbnail() return the image not just the url, so try:

```
<div class="post-thumb">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>" >
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: paul can u check above link .i added  the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); after that is not displaying thumbnail image

Comment: Think it might be that you are trying to close the img tag incorrectly they are self closing so there is no closing tag, so should be: <img src="<?php 
     the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" />

Comment: NOW JUST ONE PROBLEM THUMNAIL IS NOT DISPLAYING AS PER THUMBNAIL SIZE ie. 150*150

Comment: Are you passing thumbnail to the function and still getting wrong image? <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>" >

Comment: <div class="post-thumb">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
         <?php the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID,'thumbnail'); ?>
         
        </a>
 </div>

Comment: https://stageserver.co/officework/dev/6-lead-generation-techniques-to-immediately-turn-your-business-into-a-sales-magnet-9-3/

Comment: done thanx alot paul  i did this :- $Img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' );   and added $img in img tag